# Email alerts from Cloudera Manager

Tags: email, hadoop, alert, cloudera, cloudera-manager

We need to set up a process that will allow us to receive email alerts based on Hadoop metrics from Cloudera Manager. E.g. a particular service going down, more than 10 datanodes getting blacklisted etc. What would be best way to achieve this in CM version 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try looking in the Cloudera Manager under Administration->Alerts?  There's quite a bit of built-in monitoring and alert configuration options there.  With regards to your example, there is a specific setting for "DataNode health" under the HDFS alerts.